# How to call Okta secured endpoint in Java?

Tags: java, openid-connect, okta

I have a system that calls a single third party API, in order to fetch a users hash password, which we store in a database. Thereafter the user can make other API calls and the system just attaches the hash from the DB.

The third party is now securing this single API where we fetch the hash using Okta and OIDC. What is the simplest way to handle this?

From what I understand, we need to redirect the user to a provided Okta URL so they can log in there, and Okta redirects back to URL we designate. We can then get an access token to call the third party API.

I am unsure of what my option are regarding Java libraries for Okta.

I have looked a little bit at https://www.pac4j.org/docs/clients/openid-connect.html, but this looks more like a library for securing APIs using Okta, which we dont need to do, just call a secured API.

Apparently Okta is also supported by the Spring boot framework, but I have no experience with Spring and we dont use it. Are there other options? Or something a lot smaller and simpler we can use, so we dont have to deep dive into Spring?

Comment: I'm quite unsure, in my eyes your question as is it currently is the question is an off topic question. Then you look for a library at the moment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to use Spring Boot, you can do everything manually in your app. I suggest you to study OIDC authorization code flow for better understanding of all the steps below:

1. You create OIDC application in Okta and assign all the users, who is planning to call 3rd party service
2. Redirect your users to Okta with /authorize call
3. Receive back authorization code after Okta returns an authenticated user back to your app
4. Exchange the code for token(s)
5. While calling your 3rd party attach the obtained token

Not sure if you are familiar with PHP, but there is an example of how to do all the same things you need with PHP (no Spring Boot, lol) https://developer.okta.com/blog/2018/07/09/five-minute-php-app-auth

Good luck!